# How to fill an input element that is in a popup using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to automate access to a specific newspaper. The problem is that to enter the email and password it is necessary to click on the sign in button and wait for a popup to open.

However, when waiting for a selector that is in the login popup, the following error is reported:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Waiting for selector `input[fieldloginemail]` failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded.
```

Could anyone help me in this case? I'm using puppeteer 19.8.5.

My code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

puppeteer
  .launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null })
  .then(async (browser) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://pressreader.df.cl/diario-financiero");
    await page.waitForSelector(".btn-login, .toolbar-button-signin", {
      visible: true,
    });
    await page.click(".btn-login, .toolbar-button-signin");

    const emailSelector = 'input[fieldloginemail]'
    const passwordSelector = 'input[fieldloginpassword]'

    await page.waitForSelector(emailSelector)
    await page.waitForSelector(passwordSelector)

    await page.type(emailSelector, 'foo@bar.com')
    await page.type(passwordSelector, 'myPassword')
    await page.click('button[actionlogin]')

    await browser.close();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the auth modal is inside an iframe. Here's how I'd go about this:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.7.2

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

  const btn = await page.waitForSelector(".btn-login, .toolbar-button-signin");
  await btn.evaluate(el => el.click());

  const frameEl = await page.waitForSelector('iframe[id^="piano-id"]');
  const frame = await frameEl.contentFrame();

  const email = await frame.waitForSelector("input[fieldloginemail]");
  await email.focus();
  await email.type("foo@bar.com");

  const pw = await frame.waitForSelector("input[fieldloginpassword]");
  await pw.focus();
  await pw.type("myPassword");

  await frame.click("button[actionlogin]");
  await page.screenshot({path: "login.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

The `.focus()` seems to be necessary because some asynchronous event seems to take focus away from the input, causing characters to be missed. I haven't tested it extensively, so keep an eye on it.

I'm also using `.evaluate(el => el.click())` for the main button since visibility seems spotty and it triggers fine with an untrusted event.

In general, the site is a slow, fussy, heavily-animated modern site. Blocking CSS and images might help speed and reliability.

Minor point, but you can [use the return value of `waitForSelector`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-using-the-return-value-of-waitforselector-and-waitforxpath).